# Merge 2 tiff files in a single without losing tag and custom data

Tags: .net, merge, tags, tiff

I've a document which is scanned by a third party software and it produce 2 tiff files, front and rear. Each file has tags and some custom tags (for a total of 20 tags). So when I merge these 2 files, it's important to get all of them in 2 separate pages (with image) into a multi-page tiff.

Moreover, the third party software add some record to the document (example : scan date, document type, ...) which is the same for both files. When I merge these two files I only need this data once.

How should I proceed programmatically in .Net ?

**UPDATE #1**

Actually, I'm able to merge both tiff but the result doesn't contains all custom tags (or propertyItem). But I add 1/4 missing tag (can't add the 3 others like I've add the first), and get some metadata records, it's sounds like a good start!

Answer (score 0):

See this:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16904/Save-images-into-a-multi-page-TIFF-file-or-add-ima

To get the scanned data from one image only, you will need OCR procedures and it will make your program a lot more difficult - you will need to translate image-to-text for both images, locate them in the graphics and strip them, and so forth...

Comment: Hi @David, thank you for adding an answer but it doesn't make all the job done. The both file are merged but I've lost many custom tags (or propertyItem) and all metadata about these images.